# NodeJS Create stream from buffer

Tags: node.js

I save my file to a buffer and cache the buffer for future use. Now I want to use the buffer to create a stream so that I can pipe it to the response again. Is this possible? and if it is then how?

Answer (score 2):

I found this most promising, thanks to felixge (node committer, esp stream module)
 https://github.com/felixge/node-combined-stream

Example of piping a file to buffer first then construct a stream and pipe to process std out, modified from the [article](http://technosophos.com/content/using-string-stream-reader-nodejs)

(you can pipe from file systems stream directly, here is for illustrate)

#### Async loading buffer from file

```
var fs = require("fs");
var fileName = "image.jpg";

var CombinedStream = require('combined-stream');

var combinedStream = CombinedStream.create();

fs.exists(fileName, function(exists) {
  if (exists) {
    fs.stat(fileName, function(error, stats) {
      fs.open(fileName, "r", function(error, fd) {
        var buffer = new Buffer(stats.size);
        fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, null, function(error, bytesRead, buffer) {
             fs.close(fd);

           //even the file stream closed
           combinedStream.append(buffer);
           combinedStream.pipe(process.stdout);


        });
      });
    });
  }
});
```

#### Sync Loading buffer from file:

```
//get buffer
var buffer = readFileSync(fileName);
//or do it yourself
var stats = fs.statSync(fileName);
var buffer = new Buffer(stats.size);
var fd = fs.openSync(fileName,"r");
fs.readSync(fd,buffer,0,buffer.length,null);
fs.close(fd);

combinedStream.append(buffer);
combinedStream.pipe(process.stdout);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no native functionality in node for doing this. You might search around a bit to see if there are third-party libraries for it. If there aren't, it's possible, if a bit tedious, to write your own module that will do it, since any class that implements all the methods and properties listed in the documentation for `Stream` and emits and responds to all the events listed in the documentation *is*, by definition, a `Stream` and can be used anywhere that node's built-in `Stream`s can.