# How to create a read stream of a AWS S3 object in a async function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, async-await

How to create a read stream of a AWS S3 object in a async function?

If I try

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  var csvreadstream = await s3.getObject({ Bucket: bucket, Key: filename }).promise().createReadStream()
}
```

or

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  var s3Object = await s3.getObject({ Bucket: bucket, Key: filename }).promise();
  var csvreadstream = s3Object.createReadStream();
}
```

I get

```
{
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "(intermediate value).createReadStream is not a function",
  "trace": [
    "TypeError: (intermediate value).createReadStream is not a function",
    "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/app.js:29:86)",
    "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)"
  ]
}
```

Can anyone advice how to create a read stream from an S3 object in an async (async/await manner) function?
Thank you!

Thanks to Mark B I am a step further:

```html
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const utils = require('./utils');
const csv = require('fast-csv');
const stream = require('stream');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log("Incoming Event: ", JSON.stringify(event));
    const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    const filename = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    const message = `File is uploaded in - ${bucket} -> ${filename}`;
    console.log(message);
    
    var errors = [];

    const splittedFilename = filename.split('.');
    const reportFilename = splittedFilename[0] + "Report." + splittedFilename[1];
    const reportBucket = 'external.transactions.reports';
    
    var s3object = (await s3.getObject({ Bucket: bucket, Key: filename }).promise());
    var csvreadstream = new stream.Readable();
    csvreadstream._read = () => {};
    csvreadstream.push(s3object.Body);
   
    csvreadstream
    .pipe(csv.parse({ headers: true }))
    .on('data', async function(data){
        this.pause();
        console.log("DATA: " + data);
        await utils.filterLogic(data, errors);
        this.resume();
    })
    .on('end', async function(){
        console.log("END");
        await utils.writeErrorReport(errors, s3, reportBucket, reportFilename);
    })
};
```

However, the stream seems not to get processed, like calling `.on()`
Does anyone have an advice how to process the read stream in an async function?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `s3Object.Body` would return a Buffer. You could then look at a technique like the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869752/nodejs-create-stream-from-buffer) if you need to convert a Buffer to a Stream.

Comment: Thank you very much Mark B. Yes, that works!

    var s3object = (await s3.getObject({ Bucket: bucket, Key: filename }).promise());
    var csvreadstream = new stream.Readable();
    csvreadstream._read = () => {};
    csvreadstream.push(s3object.Body);

Answer (score 14):

Late to the party, but I believe you simply wanted to do:

```
var readableStream = await s3.getObject({ Bucket: bucket, Key: filename }).createReadStream();
```

This returns a readable stream without downloading the whole object up-front using .promise() and waiting for it to be resolved, and then after the whole buffer was downloaded converting it manually to a readable stream.