# Get AWS S3 file separately and join them?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Everyday, I download few large file from S3.
I use only `getObject` function.

Sometimes, I was worried that my code's memory over limit.

Is it possible get file separately from `s3` and merge them?

I attach my current code for help understand.

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fs  = require('fs');

function getOneFile() {
    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: "",
        secretAccessKey: "",
        region: "",
        endpoint: ""
    });

    var s3 = new AWS.S3();

    var params = {
        Bucket: "bucket-name",
        Key: "key"
    };

    // If file size is too big,
    // How can I change under code?
    s3.getObject(params, function (err, data) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            fs.writeFileSync("downloads/saveName.txt", data.Body.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical way to handle big files in Node.js is by utilizing [Streams](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/stream.html). You'd obtain a ReadableStream, create a WritableStream using `fs.createWriteStream`, and `pipe` (or, preferably, `pipeline`) one into the other - this is explained well in the API docs for streams.

Now, the question remains: how do we make the AWS SDK return a ReadableStream instead of one big Buffer?

The API reference documents the callback parameters that you get in response to s3.getObject like this:

```
Body — (Buffer(Node.js), Typed Array(Browser), ReadableStream)
Object data.
```

This is quite unhelpful, and seems to indicate that you can get several different types of Body as a callback parameter - either a Buffer or a ReadableStream, but it's not clear how to choose which one you want.

However, AWS.Request (the base class) has a `.createReadStream()` method, which should do what you want:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html#createReadStream-property

Here is an existing StackOverflow answer with a usage example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65683054/6098312